# generating a random number without repetitions

Tags: javascript, loops, random

I am trying to generate a series of random numbers generating every time a different one, I came up with a simple function in javascript but it still gives me the same number consecutively and I fail to understand why, can anyone help me please

```
function random(){
  var randNum;
  var prevnumb;
  do{
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  } while(prevnumb == randNum);
  prevnumb = randNum;
  return randNum;
}
```

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't work_".

Comment: prevnumb is a local variable, and doesn't keep it's value between function calls

Comment: Move `var prevnum` outside the function - Tada!

Comment: Or return a function instead of randNum and let that returned function return the randNum

Comment: @Teemu Yes, that is right.  I'm not writing a random sequence generator for them.  That's enough to get them started, hence a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Teemu apologies, I see now my question wasn't clear, I edited the title, regarding the 'It doesn't work' I meant that the function still give me the same number more than once.

Comment: @Federico Yes, the question is much better now. Always ask this way, and you'll get good answers. Currently the given answers are not useful to you (might be to some future readers, though), since they are answering the original, a bit confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the previous number to your function, and I would recommend passing the highest desired random number as well. Do not use floor() or you will never get a random 0. If you find it convenient, you create a parameterless function handling this like

```js
function randomizer(max) {
  var prevNum;
  return function() {
    var randNum;
    if (!max) return 0;
    while (1) {
      randNum = parseInt(Math.random() * (max + 1));
      if (prevNum !== randNum) {
        break;
      }
    }
    prevNum = randNum;
    return randNum;
  }
}

var last;
var rnd = randomizer(2);
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var cur = rnd();
  console.info("difference ", last - cur, " is not 0");
  last = cur;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I just had to declare the previous number var outside the function, pass it as parameter and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store previous value into an array and you can validate,

```
function random(){
  var randNum;
  randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  if(!prevnumb.contains(randNum)){
  prevnumb.push(randNum);
  } 
  return randNum;
}
```